# Why a store function in the sysfs API of the Linux Kernel needs to return used bytes?

Tags: linux, kernel, sysfs

From the documentation:

> - store() should return the number of bytes used from the buffer. If the
>     entire buffer has been used, just return the count argument.

What does it do with this value? What's the difference if from a buffer of size FOO I read 4 and not 6 bytes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must realize that by implementing a sysfs file, you are trying to behave like a file.

Let's see this from the other side first. From the man page of `fwrite(3)`:

> **RETURN VALUE**
>   fread()  and  fwrite() return the number of items successfully read or written (i.e., not the number of characters).  If an error occurs, or the end-of-file is
>     reached, the return value is a short item count (or zero).

And even better, from the man page of `write(2)`:

> The number of bytes written may be less than count if, for example, there is insufficient space on the underlying physical medium, or the RLIMIT_FSIZE resource
>     limit is encountered (see setrlimit(2)), or the call was interrupted by a signal handler after having written less than count bytes.  (See also pipe(7).)

What this means is that `store()`, which is implementing the other end of the `write(2)` function for your particular file should return the number of bytes written (i.e. read by you), in the very least so that `write(2)` can return that value to the user.

In most cases, if there is no error in the input, you would just want to return `count` to acknowledge that you have read everything and all is ok.

Comment: Great (and fast!) answer :-) Thanks!

Comment: @maayank, quick question. Did you manage to figure out how to work with directories in sysfs? I use `kobject_create_and_add` which takes a parent node for creating a directory, but I don't know how to get the pointer to already existing nodes! (I give `NULL` so it creates a directory in the root of sysfs).

Comment: It's a bit different (same idea, different function names) if you use devices/classes/buses etc., but what I do is creating a class structure and register it with class_register(). If I need files inside that directory I add (before registration) default attributes. If I need directories inside the class directory I created I create a device with device_create() (it receives the class structure for reference) and add the "files" for that in the "dev_attrs" field of the class structure. I don't know if that's the "Linux Kernel way", but it conforms to the project spec I'm working with.

Comment: ^^ this will give you with class FOO and device BAR and file inside BAR named FILE the file /sys/class/FOO/BAR/FILE.

If you want the folder to be under a specific /sys/something then you need to look for the specific model API that 'something' references (i.e. block devices for block)

Comment: I see, thanks. Any idea how to get the handles for `/sys/module/`? When you insert a module, there would automatically be created a folder under `/sys/module/module_name`. I would be happy to know how to add files under that specific folder. I can't imagine a function like `sysfs_get_self()` doesn't exist.

Comment: I think you can add parameter "files" under /sys/module/mymodule/parameters with the macro module_param. See http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-2-sect-8 for exact argument details.